# xamps vs xibo - Appache stop working

Tags: server, xampp

I am using xibo open source on localhost server, recently I got error "Appache stop working"
I checked the error logs:

```
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.257000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH00428: Parent: child process 3964 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.915000 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.987000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.987000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.987000 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:20.989000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5204:tid 232] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2700
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.188000 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 684:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.293000 2016] [core:warn] [pid 684:tid 232] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.530000 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 684:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.605000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 232] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.605000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 232] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.605000 2016] [core:notice] [pid 684:tid 232] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:24.608000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 684:tid 232] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5364
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:25.607000 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5364:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:25.944000 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5364:tid 248] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Sep 21 08:34:26.015000 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5364:tid 248] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

httpd.conf
http://pastebin.com/1QbmV4xV

httpd-ssl.conf
http://pastebin.com/X5vStUZu

Can you please help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: http-xampp.conf
http://pastebin.com/pAvzjQfQ

php.ini
http://pastebin.com/AyRRUwCb

config.inc.php
http://pastebin.com/S4WsBeA0

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to isolate the problem and post the relevant code *in your question*. Do not use external links such as pastebin, your question will be invalid if the external links are broken.

Comment: Can you confirm the error spelling? _Appache_ or _Apache_?